# Django multiple params link

Tags: python, django

I have this urls.py

```
path('calendar/<dt:date>/', views.CertainDay.as_view(), name="classrooms"),
path('calendar/<dt:date>/<int:classroom>/', views.ScheduleList.as_view(), name="schedule"),
```

first path with one args works good with reverse func in some file

how i can do this -> `from .../calendar/2020-01-01 to .../calendar/2020-01-01/100` in template without using context and 2 args like `url " " date arg2`

something like `<a href = "{% url 'schedule' *** %}>` tries reverse full path with two args

Comment: Hi, its not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to understand if it is possible to continue the link by passing only one parameter. In fact, I want me to go from /calendar to /calendar/<date>/ (here I pass 1 parameter) through <a>, and from this page to go further to /calendar/<date>/<number> also through <a> passing only the parameter number, so the date will remain from the previous transition. What is the best way to do it? I have done it now by passing the date in context. Sorry for my eng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on URL `www.website.com/calendar/2020-01-01/` and you want to go on `www.website.com/calendar/2020-01-01/100/`, you can have a relative link like this :

```
<a href="100/">Go to 100</a>
```

No need to use the template function `{% url 'schedule' *** %}` but this is not the cleaner solution since it is harder to debug.

Comment: Thx for reply, maybe u can advise  some better approach?